# map through object and return array with existing values changed new value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, functional-programming, lodash

I have existing values in a database, and would like to change them to return something else

```
 const newObj = {
      '#1': '1',
      '#2': '2'
      '#3': '3',
      '#4': '4',
      '#5': '5',
      '#6': '6'
            }
```

The keys in newObj is the existing obj id from the db, and the values are what I want them changed to.

I create a new array with the existing data from the database

```
  const arrOfValues = answer.value.map(item => ({
              id: item.id,
              text: item.text, // obj prop I want changed
              value: item.value,
            }))
```

I loop through the original array (before it was saved to db) and find the matching obj in the db

```
 oringintalArrayOfObjs.forEach(item => {
              let changeOldToNew = 't'
              const found = arrOfValues.find(dbObj => dbObj.id === item.id)
              // returns matching obj from DB
              // {'id': '#1', 'text': 'number 1', 'value': '1'}

              
              // create new array with updated item.text
              const newArr = arrOfValues.map(item => {
                _.forEach(newObj, (key, value) => {
                  if (found.id === newObj[key]) {
                    // change found.text to newObj[value]
                    changeOldToNew = newObj[value]
                  } else {
                    changeOldToNew = found.text
                  }
                })


                // tried to use spread here to stop overwriting existing values
                return { ...item.text, text: changeOldToNew, value: item.value }
              })

  
              result = _.map(newArr, index => _.at(index, 'text', 'value').join(': '))
            })
```

At the moment this returns an array of strings which looks like this

```
["6: 1",
"6: 2",
"6: 3",
"6: 4",
"6: 5",
"6: 6",
"6: 7"]
```

expected output should be:

```
   ["1: 1",
    "2: 2",
    "3: 3",
    "4: 4",
    "5: 5",
    "6: 6",
    "7: 7"]
```

My guess is that because newArr being built for each item in `oringintalArrayOfObjs` it's overwriting my item.text and I'm not sure how to stop it?

Should I build newArr outside of my `oringintalArrayOfObjs`?

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: What object are you transforming? How do you get the expected output?

Comment: I am transforming `found`.text

Comment: Have you provided an example of the object you are trying to transform?

Comment: This is it right here, {id: item.id, text: item.text, value: item.value,} which is inside arrOfValues, `found` is just the matching object from `arrOfValues`

Comment: Could you provide a concrete example of the values? It is hard to help without one.

Comment: I have edited my original post to show what the `found` obj contains

Comment: @iota Managed to solve this, was just a matter of cleaning up the original code and using correct datastructure